# Android Google Calendar dtstart dtend

Tags: java, android

Actually I need to create an event in Google Calendar using my app. Every thing working fine I am not able to create desire start time and end time. Can any body please help me to tell how can I generate dtstart n dtend. i.e. I need to create an event for 20/12/2010. please

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, DTSTART=20101220, DTEND=20101221 since the end is exclusive.

See [RFC 2445](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.html#sec-4.3.4) for details, but the basic grammar is below:

```
date               = date-value

date-value         = date-fullyear date-month date-mday
date-fullyear      = 4DIGIT
date-month         = 2DIGIT        ; 01-12
date-mday          = 2DIGIT        ; 01-28, 01-29, 01-30, 01-31
                                   ; based on month/year
```

Comment: I am not able create an event with the following dates, it creates an event on 01 Jan 1970!

long startTime = 20110218;
long endTime = 20110219;
event.put("dtstart", startTime);
event.put("dtend", endTime);

Any idea as to why it goes to Jan, 1970 when I clearly set it to 18 Feb 2011.